# Adding container div removes flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I'm creating a simple navbar with flexbox , but whenever i add a container `div` inside `header` to make the `width` 80% and `center` it with `margin:0 auto` flexbox's `justify-content` stops working.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #24252A;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: gray;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo img {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="brand">
      <h1>Site</h1>

    </div>

    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://banner2.cleanpng.com/20180422/srw/kisspng-logo-web-development-clip-art-site-vector-5add4dee019ee5.7373764915244528460066.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

</header>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`flex` is being applied to the direct children of `header`. When you add the `container` div, it'll apply to that but not to any of its children. To achieve what you're looking for, move the flex rules to `container` instead of `header`.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #24252A;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  background: gray;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo img {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <header>
    <div class="container">

      <div class="brand">
        <h1>Site</h1>

      </div>

      <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://banner2.cleanpng.com/20180422/srw/kisspng-logo-web-development-clip-art-site-vector-5add4dee019ee5.7373764915244528460066.jpg" alt="">
      </div>

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

  </header>


</body>
```